Is the strict topology stronger than the weak* topology on the Fourier-Stieltjes algebra?
Let $G$ be a locally compact group and $B(G)$ its Fourier-Stieltjes algebra.
It can be defined as either the dual of the group C$^*$-algebra $C^*(G)$ or the linear span of continuous positive definite functions on $G$.
As a dual of $C^*(G)$, the weak$^*$ topology is naturally defined on $B(G)$.
Considering $B(G)$ as a subalgebra of $C_b(G)$, we may also consider the strict topology with respect to $C_0(G)$.
Is this strict topology stronger than the weak$^*$ topology on $B(G)$?
If so, then how about the strict topology with respect to the Fourier algebra $A(G)$ in $B(G)$?
Thank you in advance.

Can you write down how convergence of a net in $B(G)$ in the weak*-topology works?

Have you checked the book by Kaniuth & Lau? Especially pls. see $\S$ 3.7 https://books.google.ca/books?id=RmhjDwAAQBAJ

No I didn't and the answer was there.

I think the book mainly deals with the comparison on the unit ball. But I realized the original problem I concerned with is solved by considering only on the unit ball. Thank you for letting me know a wonderful reference.
